# akka actor remote started, but can't telnet

Tags: scala, actor, akka-remote-actor

from the running log of the following, it said remote is started fine and listen on port of 2552:

```
[INFO] [08/16/2014 21:05:57.523] [run-main-0] [Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [08/16/2014 21:05:57.692] [run-main-0] [Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.1.1:2552]
[INFO] [08/16/2014 21:05:57.694] [run-main-0] [Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.1.1:2552]
```

But telnet that port failed. Does that mean remote can't be verified using telnet, or the
remoting has problem?
    Trying 127.0.0.1...
    telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: The IP listed in the logs is "127.0.1.1" try that.

Comment: yes, you are correct.